# Office WebApps 2013 Not working for one web application

Tags: 2013, web-application, office-web-apps

[image]We have 4 web applications in our SharePoint 2013 environment. Office WebApps is working fine for 3 web applications but for one web application,we are getting error "sorry,there was a problem we cannot open this document.If this happens again,try opening the document in Microsoft word

On analyzing the Office WebApp logs,I came across the below error:

> Error message from host: Unhandled exception in WOPI Handler: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object., 
>   WOPICheckFolder,WACSERVER FileNotFound
>   [url:http://SiteURL/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/folders/814283ffcdae406d9a479064bf365a1d?access_token=REDACTED_1120&access_token_ttl=1484003070135

Office WebApp event Logs displays the below Error:

> Could not contact WOPI End Point. Error details - 'FileNotFound url -
>   http://SiteURL/_vti_bin/wopi.ashx/files/63f4abc64a754aa28308f8a0883e9854?access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InNLLUxEUkJ5RDBCOTlfZlZUc1UzRzJXbFV1cyJ9%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%2EE2GRYrg4beM9IUMfW%5FC4RvuA2BNUIoS%5FmHjEiHF9wRNZ%2DT7stRDd2L7nArN%5FuOfCfk3W%2D26bbKkxM4yNL5FcKk4DBKa7zLAItX587G2nmnm2XX3stUyzYNFoO1JRKCpoPAeWia7troB%2DuIJEjJe1ofonsMDqTrVy3lRNEBr%2Dh59HrcdC1PjHVRCs4BNPVljkosYYpO08DQBz1mCc%2DcrrBC3FpyvOqWkV1GBZ77l%2D7SbtZerj6mTJL%2DOLhtIAcBo%5FuEeRuy%5F6B%2D11deOGxWz8KyHAAVqWNf6S3%5FAX4VpNnQ7Y%2DZ3TP2iVSeHJPB0KziN0bnOpqOxek7pKujJBvU%5Fz9g&access_token_ttl=1484001684458'.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please check:

- Is your WebApplication configured to use Claims Authentication? OfficeWebApps won't work with Windows-Classic
- Can you Resolve your WebApplication ("SiteURL") from your OfficeWebApps Server? You could try to ping it.
- OfficeWebApps-Server has its own [ULS-Log](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zwsong/2013/04/16/where-would-you-find-uls-logs-on-office-web-apps-owa-2013-server/). Maybe you can find a more specific error there.

Comment: 1. Yes,Web App is configured to use ADFS Claims.                                                 2. Yes,able to ping SiteURL in OWA server                                                                           3. Office Web App logs has been updated in my question,also i have updated the Office WebApps Event logs

Comment: Could you please try to browse the WebApplication and the Library in an IE-Window on your OWA-Server?!

Comment: Yes,I'm able to access sites and library.

Comment: Are you doing any URL-Rewriting in IIS? Unfortunately your Error is a bit generic. Would be useful if you could give us more information on your config (Get-SPWOPIBinding; Get-OfficeWebAppsFarm; Screenshot of SharePoint AAMs and IIS-Bindings). You can anonymize your URLs, as long as they match and the protocols (HTTP vs. HTTPS) are identical.

Comment: we have http site(default zone) with windows claims authentication.https site(intranet) with ADFS claims authentication.URL re-direction from http to https has been configured. WOPI Binding is set to "External - https". In AAM,we have 3 entries for each web application as http(default),https (intranet) and https redirection url(intranet). Office Webapp configuration screenshot is attached to question

Answer (score 0):

Your WebApplication's default-Zone with Claims-Authentication is using HTTP-Protocol. You have disabled HTTP in your OfficeWebApp-Configuration. Try to enable it with the following PowerShell-command on your OfficeWebApps-Server:

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -AllowHttp:$true
```

You also have to change your WOPI-Binding in SharePoint to support HTTP. Maybe this has already been done. You can find the required steps [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431687.aspx#ConfigureMain).

Comment: but we are not using http sites. All http requests are re-directed to https

Comment: Your error-messages say, that OfficeWebApps is trying to contact SharePoint via HTTP and not HTTPS. How do you redirect to HTTPS? Screenshots of your AlternateAccessMappings and IIS-Bindings would be helpful.